# CircleCI CLI looks in wrong path for Android SDK

Tags: android, docker, circleci-2.0

I'm using the CircleCI CLI to test running my unit tests locally. Every time I run I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':appName'.
> The SDK directory '/Users/me/workspace/android-sdk-macosx' does not exist.
```

If I add in a command to run `echo $ANDROID_HOME` it correctly points to `/opt/android/sdk` I can't figure out why it's getting my local `$ANDROID_HOME` value and not what's configured in the container.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an hour of chasing my tail here's the problem. Because I'm running the CircleCI CLI locally it's not pulling all the code fresh from github, it's just copying my local file system, and my local file system has `local.properties` which points to my local android SDK home path. So I added this to my config.yml and it all works

```
steps:
      - run:
          name: remove local settings
          command: rm local.properties
```